# Libgdx How to set alarm?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I want to set alarm ya how to use broadcast receiver in libgdx programing. I don't know how to set Alarm in Libgdx. please suggest any idea ya any link how to implement. alarmManager is not working in Libgdx. How to use broadcast receiver in libgdx program.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you're looking for is android specific. LibGDX is meant to be a cross platform so it doesn't support doing that directly. You'll have to code this yourself by diving deep into the Android backend of LibGDX, see [interfacing platform specific code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code).